# How to get file(s) from FTP and copy it to another via PHP/CURL

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I know how to upload files via CURL php script. It's very nice!
But it's possible to get files from one FTP server and upload them to other via CURL/php script?

Comment: yes. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: What problem do you have that? Don't you know how to upload a file (to the second server)? Or do you actually want to transfer the files directly between servers? (i.e. not download and upload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = ["yourfile1.txt","yourfile2"];
foreach($files as $file){
$curl = curl_init();
//The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/putscript");

//  A username and password formatted as "[username]:[password]" to use for the connection.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file));
$fp = fopen($file, "r");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($fp); 
}
```

Comment: Mind f#ck today... of course its the answer. Any hint how to support more than one file?

Comment: Yes convert this to a function and your files into array then using a loop pass each one to that function

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this within a PHP script

Look into [`ftp_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)

And the various [FTP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) built into PHP

Answer (score 0):

Here I have an example you can work with. The first thing you will want to do is create a .txt file with "Hello World" as your body. Next ensure you have the ftp login credentials so you can add the file. Once you've completed that run your code somehthing like this:

```
<?php
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "XXXXXXXXXX.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$ftp_username = 'username';
$ftp_userpass = 'password';
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
$file = "hello.txt";



//upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "YourDirectory/Hello.txt", $file, FTP_ASCII))
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Once you have executed the code (will take about a minute) the file should be added to the ftp server. This example shows how to upload local to ftp using php. You can transfer between ftp servers but I know it is very time consuming using php. (about a minute for each call)